# How read file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I try to read txt file in node.js.
this txt file location is as below

```html
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/Users/PC/Desktop/tutorial/text.txt', function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data);
});
```

when run
node fileread.js
it show as follow

```html
<Buffer 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 74 65 73 74 20 66 69 6c 65 20 74 6f 20 74 65 73 74 20 66 73 20 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 20 6f 66 20 4e 6f 64 65 2e 6a 73 0d 0a>
```

how can place file path in node.js
I not understnad some exaample tutorial.they not show how to place file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Use 'utf8' or 'base64' or 'ascii' as a second parameter in readFile() method which specifies the type of encoding to read the file. Default is null.

```
var fs = require('fs'); fs.readFile('/Users/PC/Desktop/tutorial/text.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) { if (err) throw err; console.log(data); });
```

2.another way

```
var fs = require('fs'); fs.readFile('/Users/PC/Desktop/tutorial/text.txt', function (err, data) { if (err) throw err; console.log(data.toString()); });
```

toString() method's first parameter is a 'utf8' by default. This is the format Node.js uses to express the raw data. We can use 'utf8' or 'hex' or 'base64', these are type of encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "utf8" as second arg

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/Users/PC/Desktop/tutorial/text.txt',"utf8" ,function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add encoding

````js
fs.readFile("your_file", { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function(err, data ) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }

  console.log( data );
});```
````